# Why do I get 'internal error' from Paypal using this call in Django?

Tags: python, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a request that gets PayPal authentication. It is written in Curl and it works perfectly. Trying to rewrite it in Python leads to an error response(500000 internal error). Can anyone please direct me on how I would rewrite it or correct my existing code.

**CURL**

```
curl -s --insecure -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: <user_id>" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: <user_password>" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: <user_signature>" -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions -d "{\"scope\":\"EXPRESS_CHECKOUT\", \"callback\":\"<callback_url>",  \"requestEnvelope\": {\"errorLanguage\":\"en_US\"}}"
```

**PYTHON**

```
import settings
import urllib
import urllib2
from django.utils import simplejson

def home(request):
    headers = {
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": settings.USERNAME,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": settings.PASSWORD,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE": settings.SIGNATURE,
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T"
    }

    data = {"scope":"EXPRESS_CKECKOUT", callback":"http://www.example.com/success.html", "requestEnvelope": {"errorLanguage":"en_US"}}
    req = urllib2.Request("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions/", simplejson.dumps(data), urllib.urlencode(data), headers)    
    res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

typo in `"EXPRESS_CKECKOUT"` instead of `"EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"` and third argument `urllib.urlencode(data)` for `urllib2.Request` is not required.

```
data = {"scope":"EXPRESS_CHECKOUT", "callback":"http://www.example.com/success.html", "requestEnvelope": {"errorLanguage":"en_US"}}
req = urllib2.Request("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/RequestPermissions/", simplejson.dumps(data), headers)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: That is very reckless of me!! Thank you Siddick. It now works perfectly.